# Customize URL rewriting with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^reset-password/?$ /pwreset.php [NC,L]
```

It works perfectly, the question is whether it would also be possible to automatically redirect it to the new path when the PHP file is accessed directly?

For example: `example.com/pwreset.php` >> `example.com/reset-password`

There are several pages, so I needed something practical.

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=URL:https://user.example.com]
RewriteRule ^pwreset\.php$ %{ENV:URL}/reset-password [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^reset-password$ pwreset.php [END]
RewriteRule ^clientarea\.php$ %{ENV:URL}/home [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^home$ clientarea.php [END]
RewriteRule ^logout\.php$ %{ENV:URL}/logout [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php [END]
```

The difficulty is with links like this: **user.example.com/clientarea.php?action=services**

When accessed it redirects to: **user.example.com/home?action=services**

I need that in the case of these links the redirection occurs to: **user.example.com/services**

Can you help me with this new rule? And also how to simplify it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To externally redirect direct requests for `/pwreset.php` to `/reset-password` you can do something like the following *before* your existing internal rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^pwreset\.php$ /reset-password [R=301,L]
```

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is necessary in order to avoid a redirect loop, since we only want to redirect direct requests the user has made and not rewritten requests by the other directive. `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty on the initial request and set to "200" (as in 200 OK) after the first successful rewrite.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

---

> **UPDATE#1:** is there any way to put that in the same rule? Because there are many pages, then I would have to practically duplicate each line.

No, if you are using a single `.htaccess` file and you want to do everything via `.htaccess` then you would need to repeat the two directives (`RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`) for each external redirect. Without the `RewriteCond` directive (condition), the rewritten request would also be redirected - creating an endless loop.

However, you could use a 2nd `.htaccess` file in a subdirectory to handle the redirects. This would avoid the additional condition for every rule.

For example, instead of redirecting `pwreset.php` as explained above. You could *internally rewrite* all requests for `.php` files (assuming you are not accessing *any* `.php` files directly) to a subdirectory that contains another `.htaccess` with the necessary redirects.

1. Change the above redirect to a rewrite of the form:

   ```
   # Rewrite all direct requests for `.php` files to a subdirectory
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
   RewriteRule (.+\.php)$ /redirect-handler/$1 [L]
   ```

   Where `/redirect-handler` is a physical subdirectory.
2. Create `/redirect-handler/.htaccess` with the necessary redirects:

   ```
   # Redirect direct requests for .php files to the canonical URL.
   # If we are here then we know that the .php file has been called directly
   # so do not need an additional condition before each rule.

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^pwreset\.php$ /reset-password [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^another\.php$ /canonical-url [R=301,L]
   ```

---

Another alternative is to rewrite the request to a PHP script, instead of a subdirectory containing another `.htaccess` file and perform the redirect in PHP instead.

For example, your initial "redirect" becomes:

```
# Rewrite all direct requests for `.php` files to PHP script
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect-handler\.php$
RewriteRule (.+\.php)$ /redirect-handler.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Then, in `/redirect-handler.php` you would check the `$_GET['url']` var for the PHP file being requested. (Or just check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal.) Lookup the desired canonical URL and either 301 "redirect" if the request maps to a valid URL or return a 404.

You could take this a step further and manage everything in PHP - in a single script. This has the obvious advantage that you have just a single list (PHP assoc array or DB table) that contains the PHP file/canonical-url mapping. Apart from the initial rewrites in `.htaccess`, you would not need to update `.htaccess` when URLs are added/removed/updated. Although you *might* need modify your existing pages, depending on how you are including files etc. (?)

---

**UPDATE#2:** Using a single `.htaccess` file... If you are on Apache 2.4 (as opposed to 2.2) then you can just use the `END` flag on the internal rewrite (instead of the `L` flag) and this will avoid having to specify the additional condition (`RewriteCond` directive) on the "redirect".

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Canonical redirects...
RewriteRule ^pwreset\.php$ /reset-password [R=301,L]
:

# Internal rewrites...
RewriteRule ^reset-password$ pwreset.php [END]
:
```

Unlike the `L` flag, the `END` flag stops all processing, thus preventing the rewrite engine starting over.

Note that I made a few small changes to your initial rewrite...

- Removed the `NC` flag - do you really need a case-insensitive match? This would otherwise potentially create a duplicate content issue, but you should be consistently linking to a single canonical URL.
- Removed the *optional* trailing slash on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. (Same reason as above.)
- Removed the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string - it's not required and simplifies the rewrite (it now rewrites to a filesystem path - which is what it is - rather than a URL-path).

This is much simpler than the methods outlined above! (Although those methods do still have their purpose.)

Comment: Woow Cool, and is there any way to put that in the same rule? Because there are many pages, then I would have to practically duplicate each line.

Comment: No, ordinarily you would need to repeat both directives for each redirect. However, you could change your approach slightly and use another `.htaccess` file or even do everything in PHP. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I had two problems, the links do not have subdirectories and I do not have access to the php files, as they are encrypted.

How would it be to repeat only in an htaccess file in the home directory?

Comment: The idea is just to change the words of the access link, it is not a directory exactly. That is, I just want the `example.com/pwreset.php` URL to be accessed by `example.com/reset-password`.

Comment: If you are on Apache 2.4 then you can actually just use the `END`  flag to avoid the additional directives. (Sorry, I overlooked this earlier - this makes things much easier!) I've updated my answer. To clarify... "the links do not have subdirectories" - that's OK. Whether the links had subdirectories or not would not matter here. "The idea is just to change the words of the access link" - I assume you have changed the actual link in the HTML source? (Although if you don't have access to the PHP code then maybe not?!) You must still change the URL in the HTML source.

Comment: I edited your answer in update 2, can you tell me if this would be the correct way to organize the lines?

Comment: "if this would be the correct way" - Well, kind of. The two examples you added are a bit different... They are simply extensionless, ie `filename` for the canonical URL and `filename.php` for the underlying file. This does require that MultiViews is disabled. If you have many URLs like this then it can be greatly simplified.

Comment: Yes, I have several URLs, I would be grateful if you can add a new update with this simplification. There are even some URLs that are in this format: `example.com/clientarea.php?action=services` which should be redirected to: `example.com/home/services`. I don't know if it would be possible due to this redirect here: `RewriteRule ^clientarea\.php$ /home [R=301,L]`
 `RewriteRule ^home$ clientarea.php [END]`

Comment: I updated my initial question, have a look so you can better understand my difficulty. I did it following your tips.